# Replace duplicate elements to 'default'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-choice">                        
  <span class="x-editable">
     top_first
  </span>
</td>
<td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-choice">                        
  <span class="x-editable">
     top_first
  </span>
</td>
```

Необходимо написать jquery/js script, который бы при выставлении (в моем случае при выборе из селекта и нажатии на кнопку) двух одинаковых значений `span` (например, как указано выше оба `top_first`) тот, что устанавливается остался `top_first`, а второй сразу же заменялся на `default`.

Мой код пока выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on('click', '.popover-content .editable-submit', function() {
    var seen = {};
    $('.sonata-ba-list-field.sonata-ba-list-field-choice span').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (seen[text])
            $(this).text(text.replace('top_first', 'default'));
        else
            seen[text] = true;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: и что не так с твоим кодом?

Comment: Не работает пока ))

Comment: комментарии не предназначены для вставок больших участков кода. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос воспользуйся кнопкой [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Заработало !!! Нужно было добавить : seen[text] = text;